# Android: How do I get text to label my Floating Action Button from the XML file?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

The following code creates a blank floating action button (FAB):

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:c
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:fabSize="auto"
    app:tint="@color/white" />
```

[image: FAB in a sample app]

I know you can add an overlay image with

```
android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
```

or something similar, but is it possible to use text directly?

Answer (score 0):

The FloatingActionButton extends ImageButton, which does not support text.